# Pull Out Keywords and Muli-Word Keywords from Text - PHP

Tags: php, string, keyword

**I was wondering If anyone knows the best way to pull out the top reoccurring keywords/phrases from a block of text in PHP.**

I want to build my own tag cloud for an application I'm working on. The main tricky part would be pulling out 'muli-word' keywords such as "White House" and not recognising them as two separate words but one phrase.

There must be a bunch of scripts out there for this purpose, just can't seem to find any!

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little chunk I used - it parses a comma-delimited string, and prints the size accordingly:

**PHP**

```
function cs_get_tag_cloud_data($data)
{
    $data = str_replace(' ', '', $data);
    $tagwords_arr = explode(",", $data);
    $tags_arr = null;

    for( $x=0; $x<sizeof($tagwords_arr); $x++)
    {
        $word_count = get_tag_count($tagwords_arr, $tagwords_arr[$x]);

        if(in_tag_array($tags_arr, $tagwords_arr[$x]) == false)
        {
            $tags_arr[] = array("tag" => $tagwords_arr[$x], "count" => $word_count);
        }
    }

    return $tags_arr;       
}

# Get tag count
function get_tag_count($arr, $word)
{
    $wordCount = 0;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++ ) 
    {
        if ( strtoupper($arr[$i]) == strtoupper($word) ) $wordCount++;
    }
    return $wordCount;
}

# check if word already exists
function in_tag_array($arr, $search)
{
    $tag_exists = false;
    if(sizeof($arr)>0)
    {
        for($b = 0; $b < sizeof($arr); $b++) 
        {
            if (strtoupper($arr[$b]['tag']) == strtoupper($search)) 
            {
                $tag_exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tag_exists = false;
    }
    return $tag_exists;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="tag-words">
    <?  $tag_data = cs_get_tag_cloud_data($cloud_data);
        asort($tag_data);

        for($x=0; $x<sizeof($tag_data); $x++)
        {   
            $word = "";
            $value = "";
            $count = 0;
            $font_size = 0; 
            $new_font_size = 0;

            foreach($tag_data[$x] as $key => $value)
            {
                if($key == "tag") $word = $value;
                if($key == "count") $count = $value;
                if($count > 10) $count = 10;

                if($count > 0)
                {
                    $new_font_size = 0;
                    $font_size = 8;
                    $new_font_size = $font_size + ($count*3);

                    $word = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","", $word);

                    echo '<a class="tag-link" style="font-size: ' . $new_font_size . 'px;" href="#">' . $word . '</a> ';
                }
            }
        } ?>
</p>
```

It's just something I've used, but thought I'd share- maybe it helps you.

Edit:  For two-word tags, you could just do something like "White-House" and then remove the dash when you're echoing.  Just another thought.

Comment: So is this capable of picking out multiple word keywords? Can you explain in the instance of "white house".

Comment: If you want to pull out certain words, you can just create an array of your keywords and do a comparison that way.  The two-words example is just hyphenate two words so they don't get split up and then remove the dash when you're displaying the word.

Comment: My problem is I'm summarizing user generated content so am therefore unable to get them to add hyphens between key words. I need a script that can pull these common multi-word keywords from any given chunk of text. For example I could feed the text from the bible into this bad boy function and I would get a keyword list including such word as "God" and "Jesus Christ". Is this possible?

Comment: Sure - are your words comma-separated already?  Or just a string?  If their already comma separated, you can run a script before the script above that does something like this `$stringname = str_replace(' ', '-', $stringname);` - if you're getting *just* a string, unless you have a reference of words that should be with other words, you're kind of stuck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but unfortunately I do not have a reference of words I am looking for. All I have is a bunch of string data and need to generate a tag cloud from it (including those muli-word keywords). It must be possible, guess I'll have to look elsewhere.

Comment: It's not possible to understand which words are one-word words, or two-word words without either a reference or some kind of separation, other than a space.  Hope this helps.